# Axios DELETE call to CORS server triggers promise resolve on preflight OPTIONS call

Tags: javascript, cors, axios, es6-promise, preflight

I have an API with CORS setup to allow any method and headers from a specific origin.  Using axios, I am trying to make concurrent DELETE calls to the server and then reload all data upon completion of the all the delete calls, e.g.

```
//module ajax;
const deleteAsset = function(id) {
    return axios.delete('/api/Asset/' + id);
};

const getAllAssets = function() {
    return axios.get('/api/Asset/');
};


//module data
...
Promise.all(ids.map(id => { ajax.deleteAsset(id); }))
    .then(() => { ajax.getAllAssets(); });
```

The problem I am finding though, is that due to the preflight OPTIONS request, the promises are resolving after the OPTIONS request returns, not awaiting for the DELETE request (therefore reloading the data before the delete happens on the server).

Is there any way to prevent this happening and only resolve the promise on the DELETE request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is incorrect regarding OPTIONS. The non synchronization is because of your code.

You should `=> ajax.deleteAsset(id)` Or `=> {return ajax.deleteAsset(id)}` . In your case, you don't return a promise for map so you can't synchronize your promises.

You could `console.log` the `dfds` below to verify that indeed it is an array holding `Promise` (and not `undefined`)

below code should allow you to synchronize your deletions and "retrievement"

```
const dfds = ids.map(id => ajax.deleteAsset(id))
return Promise.all(dfds).then(_ => ajax.getAllAssets())
```

(alternative with return)

```
const dfds = ids.map(id => { return ajax.deleteAsset(id) })
return Promise.all(dfds).then(_ => { return ajax.getAllAssets() })
```

Comment: Oh crud.  Spectacular fail on my part.  Shows a pitfall in the arrow syntax if you're not careful...